Where Do We Set the Api Key For the Google Recaptcha V3 on Sitecore Forms?
I have implemented Google Recaptcha V3 using the tutorial from the following site https://dev.to/chandra_kodi/sitecore-google-recaptcha-v3-5d18
The issue I am having is that I am not sure where the Api Key is set. Does it get set on the template (CustomRecaptchaV3) or are there supposed to be field options in the Form Editor option for Google Recaptcha V3?
If I hard set the site key into my view, the recaptcha is loading properly, otherwise I'm getting no output for my Api Key model value. Due to this, I get a JavaScript error on pages with the form. I understand what the error means (the output is blank entirely)

Rendered source:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=grecaptcha_ready&amp;render="></script>

View
@* Generator: MvcView *@

@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@using Feature.MySite.SitecoreForms.Models

@model  GoogleRecaptchaV3Model


<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" type="hidden" value="" />

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=grecaptcha_ready&render=@Model.ApiKey"></script>
<script>
    function grecaptcha_ready() {
        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('@Model.ApiKey', { action: 'form' }).then(function (token) {
                document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)").value = token;
            });
        });
    }
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById(@Html.Raw("\"" + Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value) + "\""));
    var parent = hiddenField.parentNode;
    if (parent.classList.contains("sc-formdesign-fieldcontainer")) {
        var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
        textDiv.innerHTML = "(ReCaptcha V3 Hidden Field)";
        parent.appendChild(textDiv);
    }
</script>


using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;


namespace Feature.MySite.SitecoreForms.Models
{
    public class GoogleRecaptchaV3Model : StringInputViewModel
    {
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
        {
            base.InitItemProperties(item);

            ApiKey = Sitecore.StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["Api Key"]);
            ErrorMessage = Sitecore.StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["Error Message"]);
        }

        protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
        {
            base.UpdateItemFields(item);

            item.Fields["Api Key"].SetValue(ApiKey, true);
            item.Fields["Error Message"].SetValue(ErrorMessage, true);
        }
    }
}


Yes you are correct, APIKey item needs to added in the field options for the property editor under the below item in the core database, in order for this setting to be visible inside Sitecore Form dashboard.
/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/GoogleReCaptchaV3/Details

This item needs to be derived from following template and the binding configuration for this field to be added as attached.
/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Forms/Form/Templates/FormTextBox Parameters


Thereafter we need to link this item to the field inside the ControlDefinitions field of the Details Item mentioned above.

Using above changes, you will be to edit API key while you add the recaptcha field inside the Sitecore Form dashboard.
Note: You can edit the API key from content editor too, by navigating to the form recaptcha field created inside Sitecore -> Forms folder.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

This helped! Thank you!

Glad to hear that @elke_wtf..Thank you!!!
